# Responsive Material UI Timeline

Tags: typescript, material-ui, next.js, timeline, tsx

It is the first time I am using Material Ui and I am having trouble making responsive the Timeline. Currently I am using the aling 'alternate', but I woul like it to be displayed as align='left' when is in a mobile or certain width. I tried diffferent approaches but none worked.
The project is a Next.Js app with Typescript. This is the code:

```
<Timeline align={matches ? 'alternate' : 'left'}>
    <TimelineItem className={classes.primaryTail}>
        <TimelineOppositeContent>
            <h5>2015</h5>
        </TimelineOppositeContent>
        <TimelineSeparator>
            <TimelineDot>
                <FaUniversity size='1.5em' />
            </TimelineDot>
            <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent>
            <Paper elevation={24} className={classes.paper}>
                <h5>Some title</h5>
                <p>Some paragraph</p>
            </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
    </TimelineItem>
</Timeline>
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: error with "up"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use `useMediaQuery`, like this:

```
const theme = useTheme();
const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'));


<Timeline align={matches?'alternate':'left'}>
  ...
</Timeline>
```

Here if the size is medium (md) or up it'll use `alternate` and if it's smaller it'll use `left`.

Comment: Thanks @Neil but, I get an error with "up"

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios can you send the error message please?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the error to the original question

Comment: Thanks !
I've updated my answer to add the useTheme hook. However if that doesn't solve your issue, maybe try [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67121335/7507743).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is too late. Still writing this answer to help people like me.

if you do not add TimelineOppositeContent then, timeline will be visible at center. To Make it left align use below code

```
 <TimelineItem>
    <TimelineOppositeContent sx={{ display: 'none' }}></TimelineOppositeContent>
    <TimelineSeparator><TimelineDot /><TimelineConnector /></TimelineSeparator>
    <TimelineContent>Eat</TimelineContent>
</TimelineItem>
```

If you do not add Timeline Opposite content then ::before will add space to the left making timeline at center. So, it is good to have TimelineOppositeContent and hide it.