# Adjust font size for Autocomplete Dropdown in MUI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have successfully adjusted the font size of the `TextField` in my `Autocomplete`.
The problem is that I also wanted to adjust the font size of the dropdown.
How will I do it?

Codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-forked-d1jjn?file=/src/index.js).

```
<Autocomplete
  classes={{ input: classes.autoComplete }}
  value={selectedOption ?? ""}
  onChange={(e, value) => handleOptionChange(value)}
  options={options}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ""}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="freeSolo"
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to override CSS rule `option` ([doc](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/#css))

```
<Autocomplete
  classes={{
    input: classes.autoComplete,
    option: classes.autoComplete
  }}
  // ...
/>
```

[image: Edit Material UI Autocomplete (forked)]

Comment: Thank you. How about on material v5? Is makeStyles still good?

Comment: I think it depends on which we feel convenient to use. And on v5, you could try [sx prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)

Comment: Ok cool. But what do you recommend? will they remove makeStyles in the future or no?

Comment: @Joseph Don't use `makeStyles` in v5 as it's deprecated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69678388/9449426) for more detail. The alternatives are `styled()` for reusable component and `sx` for one-off styles.

Answer (score 4):

The `fontSize` of each option in the dropdown is from [`theme.typography.body1.fontSize`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L240). If you want to change that variant globally, do that in `createTheme`:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontSize: 22,
    }
  }
})
```

This changes the font size in both `TextField` and `MenuItem`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Autocomplete {...} />
</ThemeProvider>
```

You can also change the `MuiAutocomplete` styles separately in `createTheme`:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAutocomplete: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '& label': {
            fontSize: 22,
          },
        },
        input: {
          fontSize: 22,
        },
        listbox: {
          fontSize: 22,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Or if you want to change the font size in an isolated component in v5, you can use `sx` or `styled`:

#### `sx`

```
<Autocomplete
  options={top100Films}
  ListboxProps={{
    sx: { fontSize: 22 },
  }}
  sx={{
    '& .MuiAutocomplete-input, & .MuiInputLabel-root': {
      fontSize: 22,
    },
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

#### `styled()`

```
const StyledAutocomplete = styled(Autocomplete)({
  '& .MuiAutocomplete-input, & .MuiInputLabel-root': {
    fontSize: 22,
  },
});
const Option = styled('li')({
  fontSize: 22,
});
```

```
<StyledAutocomplete
  options={top100Films}
  renderOption={(props2, option) => (
    <Option {...props2}>{option.label}</Option>
  )}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you. But I really don't want to put the styles directly from the component. Any solutions which is easier to migrate makeStyles to the new ones?

Comment: I'm using v5 alpha now. But of course I want to update it to the latest versions. So that's why I will not use makeStyles. and if there's easy alternative to it that will be supported until v6.

Comment: @Joseph the easiest alternative is `sx`, the other one is [`styled`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content) which is roughly equivalent to `makeStyles`/`withStyles` in a sense that it creates a reusable styles. Unfortunately there is no easy way to migrate to v5 because `styled` and `makeStyles` API are quite different, so you probably need to change the code by hand instead of using a codemod (there is no codemod to automate this task completely).

Answer (score 1):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  autoComplete: {
    fontSize: "10px"
  },
  // stands for .MuiAutocomplete-option
  option: {
    fontSize: "10px"all at once.
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // ...
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      classes={{ input: classes.autoComplete, option: classes.option }}
```

You may also need to add a style for `'.MuiAutocomplete-noOptions'` too which is named `noOptions` in the classes objects.
Because its `fontSize` is based on [`rem`](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/), if you want to change font size everywhere, there is also another option to change the font size of HTML and change it all at once.